# JSON parameters to be changed when deploying ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, yaml

I deploy my ARM templates using Azure DevOps.

I have a YAML file, which executes a bash code:
`bash ./deploy_eventhubs.sh`

In `deploy.eventhubs.sh` I execute the command:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group myresourcegroup --templatefile armtemp/eventhubs.json --parameters @eventhubs-params.json
```

Inside my two templates:

- eventhubs.json
- eventhubs-params.json

I have different parameters, such as `{"value": "${LOCATION}"},`
that I would like to change runtime. Location is different per use-case so I am curious how is it possible to predefine this parameter that these two JSON files use, in the YAML or Bash?

Useful resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#json-variable-substitution-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggest that you could use a parameters JSON file (as you use above), and then override it at runtime:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group testrg --name rollout01 \
    --template-file azuredeploy.json  --parameters @params.json \
    --parameters https://mysite/params.json --parameters MyValue=This MyArray=@array.json
```

so, you could conceivably do a couple of ways: construct a JSON file or literal JSON string with the expanded variable values you wish to use, and tack it on as an additional --parameters item, OR dynamically construct the entire command as a string, with $(variable) references embedded, and execute it (which has some shell injection risk).